# How to configure NetBeans autocomplete for PHP Mockery

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete

When I use Mockery in a PHPUnit test, I do something like this:

```
$mockedClass = \Mockery::mock('SomeClassName');
$mockedClass->...
```

How can I make NetBeans to autocomplete after the `$mockedClass->`? `\Mockery::mock()` returns a `MockeryInterface` but NetBeans can't figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I made little mistake in my code. The example above works, as long as you DO NOT have a `use \Mockery as ...` statement in your file. If you put the `use` statement in, NetBeans gets lost. I consider this problem solved, since I found a workaround.